# Opa Syntax Highlighting for Kate

Tags: syntax-highlighting, opa, kate

I see there are syntax highlighting extensions for Vi and Emacs in Opa binary package.  I use KDE as my desktop environment so I was wondering if anybody knows such extensions for Kate?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything available for Kate at the moment but we (MLstate, creators of Opa) are always looking for contributions and are willing to help should you decide to give it a try :).